# Scala type mismatch error in for loop

Tags: scala, types

I'm trying to write a reverse method in Scala that takes a list and returns the reverse. I have:

```
object Reverse {
  def reverseList(list: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    var reversed: List[Int] = List()
    for (i <- list) {
      reversed = i :: reversed
    }
  }
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println(reverseList(List(1,2,3,4)))
  }
}
```

But when I try to compile, I'm getting:

```
example.scala:4: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: List[Int]
    for (val i <- list) {
               ^
```

The List "list" was declared to be of type List[Int]. Why is it being recognized as type Unit?

Comment: its not complaining that list is of a wrong type but expression for returns unit when return type os List[Int] is expected

Comment: Is this for a homework/exercise? Othrwise you could just use the `reverse` method of `Seq`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `reversed` after the for loop. In Scala the last line in a function is the return value. The `for (i <- list){...}` returns `Unit`.

```
object Reverse {
  def reverseList(list: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    var reversed: List[Int] = List()
    for (i <- list) {
      reversed = i :: reversed
    }
    reversed
  }
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println(reverseList(List(1,2,3,4)))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that totally fixed it. I still don't understand why I was getting a type mismatch error though. Shouldn't the variable list still have been recognized as is was declared?

Comment: The type mismatch is because the `reverseList` function is expecting a return type of `List[Int]` but `Unit` is actually being returned by the `for` expression. Adding `reversed` as the last line in the changes the return type from `Unit` to `List[Int]` and the type mismatch error is fixed.